# Beta favicons lost their letters in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, beta-sites, favicon

I've been participating in SE for a while -- particularly in beta sites. I have an account on three and I checked my account page today. I did a double take upon seeing no distinguishing white letter on any of the favicon's for the beta sites as there always have been. Were they recently removed or did I just find the bug of the day?

[image: Accounts section]

It's also missing from the Stack Exchange Dropdown:

[image: Stack Exchange Dropdown]

All the icons link to a single icon rather than site-specific icons:

[image: The Icon, Dun Dun Dun]

Comment: Repro in Chrome latest stable. "Favicon.ico" does work on these sites, but they don't show up right in the profile images

Comment: @BenBrocka So it *is* a bug?

Comment: Must be, I doubt they'd remove the only visible trace of site branding, and if they did they wouldn't only do it in one place; best I can tell these work everywhere but on the profile page.

Comment: It seems every beta site on the network was just graduated. Congratulations to all!

Comment: Seems fine to me now.. Luke you still see this problem?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd are you looking at the icons in the profile? They're still bugged for me in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @Ben good catch, lol.. from quick look with the dev tools it appears like innocent mistake - they are using the generic blank icon http://cdn.sstatic.net/beta/img/favicon.ico for all beta sites instead of the proper icon e.g. http://cdn.sstatic.net/music/img/favicon.ico

Comment: @BenBrocka How long does it usually take these type of things to be fixed?

Comment: Depends who sees it/who has to fix it. If Jin (SE's designer) has to fix it, it might be a while, I think he's crazy busy at the moment. Don't think he'd need to be involved though, the icons are probably just pulling the wrong files or something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops. I centralized all the code where we decide where to pull a favicon from with a few benefits:

- Less of that same. damn. code. everywhere.
- Every reference is now the CDN instead of `site.com/favicon.ico` (which ended up being a 302 to the CDN anyway)
- Every reference being the CDN is the same as the in-page `<link rel="shortcut icon">` element, which means you already have that file for the sites you frequent.

However, beta sites are a tad bit different, they share images so pulling the `favicon.ico` Url from that path as a base was incorrect...it should be the site's root content path and the `img/favicon.ico` beneath *that*.  This will be corrected in the next build rolling out right now.

Comment: Looks like [this is the same bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227975/why-does-the-logo-not-show-up-when-signing-up-for-a-site-and-confirming-the-acco), in a different place?