# Economics.SE's favicon is missing in action

Tags: bug, design, favicon, retina

A question from [Economics.SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) popped up in the "Hot Network Questions" list, and I couldn't help but notice that its icon is a little bit... lacking.

> [image]

Shouldn't there be some letters there or something? Maybe "Ec"? Both the main site and the meta are equally nondescript.

> [image]
>   [image]

---

As pointed out by [hichris123](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/237685/hichris123) in the comments, this is a high-DPI specific issue.

> This is another one of those "shows up on normal DPI, but breaks on high DPI" bugs because [the 32x32 sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png) is missing the Ec, but [the 16x16 sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png) is not.

Comment: This is another one of those "shows up on normal DPI, but breaks on high DPI" bugs because [the 32x32 sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png) is missing the Ec, but [the 16x16 sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png) is not.

Comment: Could not reproduce on Windows 8.1 Google Chrome.

Comment: @FollowMyProposals See hichris123's comment above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beta favicons lost their letters in profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142201/beta-favicons-lost-their-letters-in-profile)

Comment: @FollowMyProposals That report has (status-completed). If the same behavior appears again, it's a new bug report, not a duplicate.